# Does model.fit() reset metrics after each epoch? How to reset metrics manually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, metrics

As far as I understand, model.fit(epochs=NUM_EPOCHS) does not reset metrics for each epoch. My code for metrics and model.fit() looks like this (simplified):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import applications

NUM_CLASSES = 4
INPUT_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3)
MODELS = {
    'DenseNet121': applications.DenseNet121,
    'DenseNet169': applications.DenseNet169
}
REDUCE_LR_PATIENCE = 2
REDUCE_LR_FACTOR = 0.7
EARLY_STOPPING_PATIENCE = 4


for modelName, model in MODELS.items():

    loadedModel = model(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                        pooling='avg', input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

    sequentialModel = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    sequentialModel.add(loadedModel)
    sequentialModel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

    aucCurve = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve = 'ROC', multi_label = True)
    categoricalAccuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    F1Score  = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes = NUM_CLASSES, average = 'macro', threshold = None)
    metrics = [aucCurve, categoricalAccuracy, F1Score]

    sequentialModel.compile(metrics=metrics)

    callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=REDUCE_LR_PATIENCE, verbose=1, factor=REDUCE_LR_FACTOR),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, patience=EARLY_STOPPING_PATIENCE),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=modelName + '_epoch-{epoch:02d}.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=False, verbose=1),
    tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(modelName + '_training.csv')]

    sequentialModel.fit(epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Perhaps I can reset metrics by doing a for loop in range of NUM_EPOCHS and initialize the metrics in a for loop, but I am not sure if it is a good solution. Also, I have ModelCheckpoint and CSVLogger callbacks, which require an epoch number from model.fit(), so it won't really work if I do a for loop.

Do you have any suggestions on how to reset metrics for each epoch? Is doing a for loop in range of NUM_EPOCHS the only solution here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, metrics are calculated per epoch. They are not averaged over the epochs but they are rather averaged over the batches per epoch. You see that the metrics keep improving epoch after epoch because your model is getting trained.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Could you explain why when the model starts training, its metric's value (e.x. accuracy) at the start of the first epoch and at the end of the first batch is around 0.5, and at the end of the training( i.e. last epoch) the value is around 0.9. Then, when the second epoch begins and the first batch ends, the metric's value is again around 0.9, then the value might go down or up. So, why at the start of the second epoch metric's value is not again around 0.5?

Comment: Does it mean that the model weight's are already trained pretty good from the first epoch that at the start of the second epoch their predictions are much better than from the first epoch, and the metric's value decreases each batch because it sees more data and predicts some labels incorrectly, but then stabilizes?

Comment: `Then, when the second epoch begins and the first batch ends, the metric's value is again around 0.9, then the value might go down or up.` This is because your model is getting trained

Comment: say your last epochs acc is 0.9, the current epoch will further improve the model as so its acc will further improve from 0.9 and so it goes on for the training data. For test data it will be different based on whether it is overfitting or not.

Answer (score 0):

**The behaviour is controlled by the method `reset_state`**.

Usually, it looks like

```
def reset_state(self):
    # Reset the metric state at the start of each epoch.
    self.my_state_variable.assign(0.0)
```

But can be defined differently if needed (e.g. in your own metrics when subclassing).